# Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose on osx - Nokia tutorial

Tags: c++, qt

I am following a tutorial for a word processor for my QT module at uni.

It has asked me to put set this attribute:

MainWindow::setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);

the problem comes when i run the application it causes an error saying that the application has closed unexpectedly.

Also it asked me to make a actionExit action and add to the file toolbar, which doesnt show, i am guessing that it is due to the fact that i am writing it on OSx and the exit/quit is taken care for you with the cmd+Q shortcut.

I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on this problem for me so that i know for future reference. if needed i can post the tutorial + source code.

Thanks

edit: backtrace from the debugger(hope this is correct)

```
    0   __pthread_kill      0   0x7fff8eaff212  
1   pthread_kill        0   0x7fff86f7eaf4  
2   abort       0   0x7fff86fc2dce  
3   free        0   0x7fff86f96959  
4   MainWindow::~MainWindow mainwindow.cpp  22  0x100002cff 
5   QObject::event      0   0x100e48906 
6   QWidget::event      0   0x1000ecd5e 
7   QMainWindow::event      0   0x10049cadb 
8   QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper      0   0x10009593d 
9   QApplication::notify        0   0x10009bdc4 
10  QCoreApplication::notifyInternal        0   0x100e3417c 
11  QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents       0   0x100e355a0 
12  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__      0   0x7fff90925101  
13  __CFRunLoopDoSources0       0   0x7fff90924a25  
14  __CFRunLoopRun      0   0x7fff90947dc5  
15  CFRunLoopRunSpecific        0   0x7fff909476b2  
16  RunCurrentEventLoopInMode       0   0x7fff8d0f60a4  
17  ReceiveNextEventCommon      0   0x7fff8d0f5d84  
18  BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode       0   0x7fff8d0f5cd3  
19  _DPSNextEvent       0   0x7fff91a00613  
20  -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]        0   0x7fff919ffed2  
... <More>
```

Comment: "application has closed unexpectedly." <- use a debugger, post the backtrace.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld you might laugh but i dont actually know how to do that. i have run it in the debugger, got it to crash - dialog saying: the inferior stopped because it recieve a signal fro the os, signal name: SIGABRT signal meaning: Aborted. i am not sure how to post the traceback from the qt creator debugger. Sorry

Comment: Build the application in debug mode (see Build Settings in Qt Creator). Then start the application via "Start debugging" in Qt Creator. Once it crashed, you should see a list of functions in the lower-center pane (the stack trace). In its context menu, there's an option "copy contents to clipboard". In OS X you also get the backtrace via the usual reporting dialog that comes up when an application crashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your MainWindow object declared on the stack, by any chance?  If so, then DeleteOnClose is not a good idea, simply because deleting an object that is on the stack is an error.